# ant tomcat cant compile missing HttpServlet package

Tags: ant

I am trying to deploy a web app to tomcat7. I read that tomcat provides the servlet libraries and confirmed this by looking in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib. Among others it contains:

> servlet-api.jar,  jsp-api.jar, annotations-api.jar, httpclient-4.5.3.jar 
>   httpclient-cache-4.5.3.jar,  httpcore-4.4.6.jar,   httpclient-4.5.3.jar, 
>   gson-2.6.2.jar

The relevant(I think) secion of build.xml is:

```
  <path id="compile.classpath">
    <!-- Include all JAR files that will be included in /WEB-INF/lib -->
    <!-- *** CUSTOMIZE HERE AS REQUIRED BY YOUR APPLICATION *** -->
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/*"/>
    <!-- Include all elements that Tomcat exposes to applications -->
    <fileset dir="${catalina.home}/bin">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${catalina.home}/lib"/>
    <fileset dir="${catalina.home}/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
```

how come the app doesn't compile saying unknown symbol ? I also have those files in the project folder /lib:

```
symbol:   class HttpSession
    [javac]   location: class QuestionPageServlet
    [javac] /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/src/flashcardshark/servlet/QuestionPageServlet.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             String responseMessage = new Gson().toJson("card successfully udpated");
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Gson
    [javac]   location: class QuestionPageServlet
    [javac] /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/src/flashcardshark/servlet/QuestionPageServlet.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable HttpServletResponse
    [javac]   location: class QuestionPageServlet
    [javac] /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/src/flashcardshark/servlet/QuestionPageServlet.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

EDIT: I download javaee-8 from oracles website set J2EE_HOME accordingly and added the following to the above section of the build file and it still does not compile:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/*"/>
    <fileset dir="${catalina.home}/bin">      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${catalina.home}/lib"/>
    <fileset dir="${catalina.home}/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path = "${env.J2EE_HOME}/${j2ee.jar}"/>
   <fileset dir = "lib">
      <include name = "**/*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
  </path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to writing ant build scripts: but this is what I did to make it compile:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.home}"
          destdir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes"
            debug="${compile.debug}"
           includes="${basedir}/lib/*"
      deprecation="${compile.deprecation}"
         optimize="${compile.optimize}">
```

the includes option on the  is what did it.